# Unexpected token in attribute selector: '!'

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, slideshow

what to do? where to start? my slideshow doesnt show images on firefox, chrome. works fine with safari.

Comment: You could start by posting your code...

Answer (score 3):

I believe that is due to a JQuery warning message. There is more information on that particular (apparently harmless) warning here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7535

If this is, indeed, what is causing you grief, don't hold your breath for a fix - it's a "wontfix" ticket for them...